# Cannot add Microsoft Detours to project (Compile errors)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, detours

I'm trying to add **Microsoft Detours 3.0**  to my project.

I compiled the project with nmake in the readme instructions on the Github, I then went to my project properties and added

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\include
```

in the additional include directory.

I can then do the `#include <detours.h>` without seeing any errors; however, when I go to compile the program, there are hundreds of syntax errors in the detours.h file directly

```
Error E0020 identifier "VOID" is undefined  testdetours C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\include\detours.h 468
```

As well as

```
Error C1189 #error:  Unknown architecture (x86, amd64, ia64, arm, arm64)    testdetours C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\include\detours.h 47
```

[Screenshots of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd2Pi.png)

Comment: Does #including windows.h before detours.h help?

Comment: This fixed it, thank you Jeffrey!